# error when I implement Android HAL for Invensense MPU-9250

Tags: java, android, linux, android-sensors, iio

I am writing HAL ( Hardware Abstraction Layer) for MPU-9250

I copied a Packages from  [here](https://github.com/NoelMacwan/Kernel-10.4.1.B.0.101/tree/master/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu) to under drivers/staging/iio/imu in my android kernel

and then from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/invensense/+/jb-mr2.0.0-release/libsensors_iio/) to under android/device/ti/blaze/libsensors in my android sources

here is logcat :

```
I/MLLITE  (  302): sensor type path: 
/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_magn_scale
I/MLLITE  (  302): found directory
I/MLLITE  (  302): name path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/name
I/MLLITE  (  302): name found: mpu9250 now test for mpuxxxx
I/MLLITE  (  302): name path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/secondary_name
I/MLLITE  (  302): secondary name found: AK8963
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:Secondary Chip Id: AK8963
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/compass_matrix (16566802982)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:compass mounting matrix: +0 +1 +0 -1 +0 +0 +0 +0 +1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPLSensor constructor : NumSensors = 15
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Chip ID= MPU9250
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/scan_elements/in_timestamp_en (16569213871)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 480 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/length (16569305423)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:iio iio_fd opened : 89
I/Sensors (  302): pressuresensor path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:Secondary Chip Id: BMP280
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16570587162)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16576141361)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:dmp state = 0, count = 1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:load dmp: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_firmware
I/MPL-loaddmp(  302): dmp firmware size to write = 2634
I/MPL-loaddmp(  302): Bytes written = 2634
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:DMP loaded
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:gyro temperature path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/temperature
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:temperature_fd opened: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/temperature
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_scale (16808013919)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Gyro FSR used 2000
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_self_test_scale (16808105472)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:Error opening gyro self test scale
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:factory gyro x offset path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_x_offset
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:factory gyro y offset path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_y_offset
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:factory gyro z offset path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_z_offset
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:could not open factory gyro calibrated bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL: gyro x dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_x_dmp_bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL: gyro y dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_y_dmp_bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL: gyro z dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_anglvel_z_dmp_bias
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:could not open gyro DMP calibrated bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_scale (16808471683)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Accel FSR used 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:accel x dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_x_dmp_bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:accel y dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_y_dmp_bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:accel z dmp bias path: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_z_dmp_bias
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:could not open accel DMP calibrated bias
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:dmp_sign_motion_fd opened : 91
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR couldn't open dmp_pedometer node
V/Sensors (  302): InvenSense MA 5.1.6 RC25
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Invensense vector compass cal enabled
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_matrix (16809295657)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:gyro mounting matrix: -1 +0 +0 +0 +1 +0 +0 +0 -1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_matrix (16809417728)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:Couldn't read accel mounting matrix
I/Sensors (  302): HAL: Set MPL Gyro Scale 65536000
E/MLLITE  (  302): 
E/MLLITE  (  302): 
E/MLLITE  (  302): Critical error! Impossible mounting orientation given. Using Identity instead
E/MLLITE  (  302): 
I/Sensors (  302): HAL: Set MPL Accel Scale 65536
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_magn_scale (16809539798)
I/Sensors (  302): HAL: Set MPL Compass Scale 161054720
E/MPL-storeload(  302): Cannot open file "/data/inv_cal_data.bin" for read
E/MPL-storeload(  302): Could not load cal file - aborting
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:Could not open or load MPL calibration file (46)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16809661868)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_enable (16815307620)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_fifo_enable (16815399173)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_gyro_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (16815490726)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (16815551761)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_accel_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_compass_was_turned_off 0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs: echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pressure_enable (16815734866)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pressure_enable to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/batchmode_timeout to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/six_axes_q_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/ped_q_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_detector_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_indicator_on to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:batchmode timeout is zero
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/three_axes_q_on (16816070560)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/three_axes_q_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write DMP three_axis_q__on
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:DMP quaternion data was turned off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16816162113)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16816253665)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:LP Quat disabled
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:unknown gyro id -- gyro params will be wrong.
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:default to use mpu3050 params
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:unknown accel id MPU9250 -- params default to bma250 and might be wrong.
V/Sensors (  302): MPLSensor::getFd returning 89
V/Sensors (  302): MPLSensor::getDmpOrientFd returning -1
V/Sensors (  302): MPLSensor::getDmpSignificantMotionFd returning 91
V/Sensors (  302): MPLSensor::getDmpPedometerFd returning -1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Gyro (handle 0) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Gyro sensor state change what=0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Gyro Uncalibrated (handle 1) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Gyro Uncalibrated sensor state change what=1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Accelerometer (handle 2) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Accelerometer sensor state change what=2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor MagneticField (handle 3) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MagneticField sensor state change what=3
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Pressure (handle 5) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Pressure sensor state change what=5
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor MagneticField Uncalibrated (handle 4) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MagneticField Uncalibrated sensor state change what=4
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Orientation (handle 6) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Orientation sensor state change what=6
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor RotationVector (handle 7) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:RotationVector sensor state change what=7
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor GameRotationVector (handle 8) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:GameRotationVector sensor state change what=8
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor LinearAccel (handle 9) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:LinearAccel sensor state change what=9
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Gravity (handle 10) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Gravity sensor state change what=10
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Significant Motion (handle 11) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16816650394)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Disabling Significant Motion
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/smd_enable (16822326663)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/smd_enable to write with error 13
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR write DMP smd_enable
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16822418216)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16822509769)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (16822601322)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (16822692874)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_accel_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor StepDetector (handle 12) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16822784427)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pedometer_on (16828399661)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pedometer_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't enable Android Pedometer
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:computeBatchSensorMask: enableSensors=0 tempBatchSensor=0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:computeBatchSensorMask: batchMode=1, mBatchEnabled=0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16828521732)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL: batch timeout set to 0ms
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_detector_on (16834075931)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_detector_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write DMP step_detector_on
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_indicator_on (16834136966)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_indicator_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write DMP step_indicator_on
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Disabling ped standalone
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (16834228519)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (16834289554)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_accel_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16834350589)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16834442142)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Ped Standalone disabled
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/ped_q_on (16834533694)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/ped_q_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write DMP ped_q_on
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Disabling ped quat
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (16834625247)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (16834686282)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_accel_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16834747317)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16834838870)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Ped Quat disabled
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Toggling step indicator to 0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_indicator_on (16834930423)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/step_indicator_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write to DMP step_indicator_on
I/Sensors (  302): Toggle back to normal 6 axis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/six_axes_q_on (16835021976)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/six_axes_q_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write DMP six_axis_q_on
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:DMP six axis quaternion data was turned off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (16835083011)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (16835174564)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL:inv_accel_was_turned_off
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16835235599)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16835327151)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:6 Axis Quat disabled
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/batchmode_timeout (16835418704)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/batchmode_timeout to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't write batchmode_timeout
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/firmware_loaded (16835479739)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/dmp_on (16835571292)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Step Counter (handle 13) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (16835693362)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pedometer_on (16841278080)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/pedometer_on to write with error 2
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR can't enable Android Pedometer
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor GeomagneticRotationVector (handle 14) dis -> dis
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:GeomagneticRotationVector sensor state change what=14
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Gyroscope
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Raw Gyroscope
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Accelerometer
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Magnetic Field
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Pressure
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Raw Magnetic Field
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Orientation
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Rotation Vector
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Game Rotation Vector
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Linear Acceleration
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Gravity
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Significant Motion
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Step Detector
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Step Counter
I/SensorService(  302): MPL Geomagnetic Rotation Vector
I/sysproc (  302): System server: starting Android runtime.
I/sysproc (  302): System server: starting Android services.
D/SensorService(  302): nuSensorService thread starting...
I/Sensors (  302): poll found=3
I/Sensors (  302): HAL: dmpSign interrupt
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:**** Motion ****
I/sysproc (  302): System server: entering thread pool.
I/SystemServer(  302): Entered the Android system server!
I/SystemServer(  302): Entropy Mixer
I/Blaze PowerHAL(  302): Initialized successfully
I/SystemServer(  302): Power Manager
I/SystemServer(  302): Activity Manager
...

V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Accelerometer (handle 2) dis -> en
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Accelerometer sensor state change what=2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:handle = 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:flags = 1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable : mEnabled = 4
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sen_mask= 0x70
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:changed = 4
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (19010803226)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enableSensors - sensors: 0x70
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enableSensors - accel enable
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable (19017852786)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_enable to write with error 2
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable (19018035892)
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_fifo_enable to write with error 2
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=2, sname=Accelerometer
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 200000000 ns, (5.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (19018859866)
D/dalvikvm(  302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 4% free 9393K/9735K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 34ms
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL accel sample rate: (mpl)=200000 us
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 5 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_rate (19024871829)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 5 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/sampling_frequency (19024993900)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (19025268558)
I/AudioPlayer(  114): mLatencyUs = 0
W/TimeInterpolator(  114): time is rewinding: -56781 Tf=1 t0=19030761 pos0=-56781 dt=0 now=19030761 last=0 now_last=0
E/WVMExtractor(  114): Failed to open libwvm.so
I/AudioPlayer(  114): mLatencyUs = 0
W/TimeInterpolator(  114): time is rewinding: -56781 Tf=1 t0=19065795 pos0=-56781 dt=0 now=19065795 last=0 now_last=0
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=2, sname=Accelerometer
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 66667000 ns, (15.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (19135192874)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL accel sample rate: (mpl)=66667 us
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_rate (19137054446)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/sampling_frequency (19137207034)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (19137329105)
D/PermissionCache(  111): checking android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER for uid=1000 => granted (366 us)
I/InputManager(  302): Starting input manager
```

...

...

```
I/ActivityManager(  302): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.acceltest/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 467
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable - sensor Gyro (handle 0) dis -> en
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:Gyro sensor state change what=0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:handle = 0
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:flags = 1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enable : mEnabled = 5
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sen_mask= 0x7f
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:changed = 1
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (30677825931)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enableSensors - sensors: 0x7f
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:enableSensors - gyro enable
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_enable (30681304935)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_fifo_enable (30682098392)
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
E/Sensors (  302): HAL:ERR open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_fifo_enable to write with error 2
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=0, sname=Gyro
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 200000000 ns, (5.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:ignore delay set due to sensor 2
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=0, sname=Gyro
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 200000000 ns, (5.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:ignore delay set due to sensor 2
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=2, sname=Accelerometer
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 66667000 ns, (15.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (30693359378)
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
D/dalvikvm(  467): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 958K, 12% free 14076K/15943K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL gyro sample rate: (mpl)=200000 us
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 5 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_rate (30705566409)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL accel sample rate: (mpl)=66667 us
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_rate (30706542972)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/sampling_frequency (30707061771)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (30707946780)
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
I/Sensors (  302): HAL:getHandle - what=2, sname=Accelerometer
V/Sensors (  302): setDelay : 66667000 ns, (15.00 Hz)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 0 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (30863861088)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL gyro sample rate: (mpl)=200000 us
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 5 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/gyro_rate (30870269779)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:MPL accel sample rate: (mpl)=66667 us
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/accel_rate (30872192387)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 15 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/sampling_frequency (30872650150)
V/Sensors (  302): HAL:sysfs:echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable (30873382572)
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched window.
I/InputDispatcher(  302): Dropping event because there is no touched
```

It was hard for me to look for linux driver and HAL for MPU - 9250

So almost sources only supports for MPU9150 or MPU6050 .. else .. not MPU9250

anyways I dont know why I couldnt get any data from IMU sensor ?
do you guys think those two sources are wrong for MPU-9250?

Also If you guys has experience for adding mpu-9250 to android Or know how to add mpu-9250 , please let me know reference and tips T^T

Comment: Identify the code which produces the "impossible mounting orientation" message and determine if that evaluation is true.  If so, correct the information it is objecting to.

Comment: Thank you for reply . I will try it. but do you know why  "Cannot open file "/data/inv_cal_data.bin" for read " is showed up ? I dont know where inv_cal_data.bin is. It seems not being generated automatically